# PHP preg_match regex send warning if not find the text

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

There is a table in my database, I want to fetch records in the table and compare with the text which user has entered, if they match, fetch and show the other fields of that row of the table.

this is my code:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM Kala2  WHERE 1";
$res = mysqli_query($db, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) //For each word
 {
  $t = $row[sharhe_kala];
  $p = $row[mark];

  if (preg_match("/$t/i", $text)) {
       if (preg_match("/$p/i", $text)) {
             *** do something ***
                           }}
```

it works but when the word which has entered by user (`$text`) is not in database it sends this warning:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '1' in

also doesn't answer when the `$row[sharhe_kala]` or `$row[mark]` is numerical

for example if `$t="KOYO"` and `$p="Ballbearing"` and user enter `$text="koyo ballbearing"` it shows the result and it's ok, but if user enters `$text="ntn zzz"` its sends this warning:

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Unknown modifier '1' in

and if `$t="222"` and `$p="Ballbearing"` and user enter `$text="222 ballbearing"` it doesn't show the result and doesn't show any warning.

Comment: What are the content of `$t` and `$p`, I think they contain special characters.

Comment: they are some names(alphabetibal)

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57960015/372239) and add reproductible example.

Comment: The dollar sign $ marks the end of regular expression checks, so
your regular expression must looks something like "/{$p}/i"

Comment: Works for me. Even when there is numerical values. You have an error elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your variables contain special characters, namely a slash (/) which you are using for your delimiters. Try `preg_quote()`'ing your variables. For example:

```
if (preg_match("/".preg_quote($t, '/')."/i", $text)) {
     if (preg_match("/".preg_quote($p, '/')."/i", $text)) {
```

Comment: yes thank you , there is no warning after using `preg_quote()` but still have no resualt if $t or $p is numerical

Comment: @ZaGol I tried using your values that you added to the question but it works for me (see https://3v4l.org/4SDoK). Issue must be elsewhere or with different values.

Comment: you are right , its ok now for all entries . thank you

Answer (score 0):

From [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the variables that you send directly in regexp.

```
$text = "222 ballbearing";
$t = 222;
$p = "Ballbearing";

if (preg_match("/{$t}/i", $text)) {
   if (preg_match("/{$p}/i", $text)) {
       echo "Match detected";
   }
}
```